# TypeError: specificMockImpl.apply is not a function

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

Trying to run an unit test for the following : using REACT JS -  Jest and enzyme
here is part of the code:

```
     componentDidMount () {
let requestSettings = this.props.getViewRequestSettings()
let linkerDefinition = requestSettings.catalog[0].resolvedtemplate[0]
if(linkerDefinition.includes('Universal')){
  let functionName = 
linkerDefinition.substr(0,linkerDefinition.indexOf('('));
```

Unit test Files : i have all the props set but not sure if its correct

TypeError: specificMockImpl.apply is not a function

Calling the props:

```
 // jest mock functions (mocks this.props.func)
const getViewRequestSettings =  jest.fn([{requestSettings :{catalog:[0], 
resolvedtemplate:[0]}}]);
// defining this.props
const baseProps = {
getViewRequestSettings,
```

ERROR:   const getViewRequestSettings =  jest.fn([{requestSettings :{catalog:[0], 
    resolvedtemplate:[0]}}]);   NOT SURE HOW TO SET UP CORRECTLY

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Passing the parameter to jest.fn doesn't return that value when the function is called in your code. Either mock the implementation or mock the return value

**[Mock implementation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions.html#mock-implementations)**

```
const extractDataFromXML = jest.fn(() => ([{ applyodata:[0], liquidoption:[0]}]));
```

**[Mock Return value](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions.html#mock-return-values)**

```
const extractDataFromXML = jest.fn();
extractDataFromXML.mockReturnValue([{ applyodata:[0], liquidoption:[0]}]);
```

Comment: same problem - I try to apply the same method you answered before but its not working now,

Comment: Did you try the first or the second method mentioned in the answer

Comment: This solves my issue. Earlier, I was mocking my function something like the below. 
someInstance.verifyOTP = jest.fn(isSuccess ? Promise.resolve('some resolve') : Promise.reject('some rejection')). It was throwing the error. But I followed your solution and changed it like someInstance.verifyOTP = jest.fn(() => isSuccess ? Promise.resolve('some resolve') : Promise.reject('some rejection')) and that's 'it. It started working. Thanks @ShubhamKhatri